# Keyboard layout choice popup shows up in Gnome when pressing Caps Lock. How to disable?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, keyboard-layout

I use Caps Lock to change keyboard input language. After upgrade to 17.10 with gnome-shell v.3.26.2-0ubuntu0.1 a popup thingie shows up in the center of the screen with available layouts to choose everytime I press Caps Lock.

But that annoying thing is taking up input focus and turns off after a couple seconds only. Not linked with input method key setting at all, i.e. I can change layout with another Alt+Shift combo and that thing doesn't show up.

UPD: That thing only shows up on single-key switch modifier (i.e. CapsLock). If I press Alt+CapsLock for example (combo not assigned to anything) - it doesn't show.

Anyone knows what is that and how do I disable that?

Comment: Try to tap the key instead of pressing it.

Comment: This is what I do. Point is to get rid of that thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me make the previous answer more precise. Install gnome tweak tool:

`$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`

Open it, then `Keyboard & Mouse` -> `Additional Layout Options` -> `Switching to another layout` choose the option `Caps Lock`. Now `gnome-tweak-tool` can be closed.

To reset the switch in the desktop options run Settings dialog, `Devices` -> `Keyboard` -> `Switch to the next input source`. I tried to set the option both to *Disabled* and to *Default*, both works.

Comment: In ubuntu 22.04 it doesnt work now. With default option in settings popup still appears, with disabled - layout not switching.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved that issue on my own. I set input language switch solely to CapsLock key without other combinations (using gnome tweak tool).
Not sure if it affects results, but I also reset next/prev input source keys to defaults (Super+Space) in keyboard settings.